# Dependency between pubsub topic and subscription using terraform script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using one terraform script to create a pub sub topic and subscription. If the subscription needs to subscribes from the topic created by the same script, is there a way to create a dependency such that terraform attempts to create the pub/sub subscription only after the topic is created?
My main file looks like this :

```
  version = ""

  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}
    
# module "Dataflow" {
 #source = "../modules/cloud-dataflow"
#} 

module "PubSubTopic" {
 source = "../modules/pubsub_topic"
}

#module "PubSubSubscription" {
# source = "../modules/pubsub_subscription"
#}

#module "CloudFunction" {
# source = "../modules/cloud-function"
#}
```

Comment: What's inside ../modules/pubsub_topic and ../pubsub_subscription ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform will attempt to create the resources following the proper order but to answer your question and what your looking for is modules dependency "depends_on".

For example, subscription module will be created only once topic resource has been already created. That way you should add the depends_on on the subscription module.

Example:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "example" {
  name       = "example"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.example.name]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.example.arn
}

module "uses-role" {
  # ...

  depends_on = [aws_iam_policy_attachment.example]
}
```

Official documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple pubsub topic and a subscription with this snippet (just add the .json for a service account with enough privileges) on your filesystem:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("account.json")}" # Or use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  project     = "__your_project_id__"
  region      = "europe-west4" # Amsterdam
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "incoming_data" {
  name = "incoming-data"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "incoming_subs" {
  name = "Subscription_for_incoming_data"
  topic =  google_pubsub_topic.incoming_data.name

  # Time since Pubsub receives a message  to deletion.
  expiration_policy {
    ttl = "300000s"
  }

  # Time from client reception to ACK
  message_retention_duration = "1200s"
  retain_acked_messages      = false
  enable_message_ordering    = false
}
```

To link a subscription with a topic in terraform, you just need to link it with:

```
topic = google_pubsub_topic.TERRAFORM_TOPIC.name
```

Be carefull with Google requirements for topic and subscription identifiers. If they're not valid, `terraform plan` will pass, but you'll get an `Error 400 : You have passed an invalid argument to the service`